# Symfony 3.2 create query with 2 subquery's

Tags: mysql, symfony, repository, symfony-3.2, createquery

In my Symfony 3.2 project, I want to show all `themes` which are used in `table1` and `table2` by `user_id` = 1.

This is the MySQL-query which works perfect in PhpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT DISTINCT themes.*
FROM themes
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM table1
     WHERE table1.theme_id = themes.id
     AND table1.user_id = 1)
OR EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM table2
     WHERE table2.theme_id = themes.id
     AND table2.user_id = 1)
ORDER BY themes.name;
```

The problem is that I couldn't translate it for my `ThemeRepository` class in my project... I tried this code:

```
public function findAllUsedByUserId($userId) {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT DISTINCT t
            FROM AppBundle:Theme t
            WHERE EXISTS
                (SELECT *
                FROM AppBundle:Table1 a
                WHERE a.theme_id = t.id
                AND a.user_id = :userId)
            OR EXISTS
                (SELECT *
                FROM AppBundle:Table2 b
                WHERE b.theme_id = t.id
                AND b.user_id = :userId)
            ORDER BY t.name ASC
        ')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->getResult();
}
```

The output is an error: `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 131: Error: Unexpected '*'`

Can someone help me with my query? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be `a` and `b` instead of `*`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks!